# How can I hide the button add to cart from customer product page?

Tags: cs-cart

I am new to cs-cart so I don't know how to how hide an add to cart button from the customer area.
`products.view`

Comment: Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: how to hide cart from header?

Comment: use cs-cart admin side to hide cart.

Comment: design->layouts->cart content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for hiding add to cart button you just look here

```
/var/www/html/design/themes/responsive/templates/buttons/add_to_cart.tpl
```

Answer (score 1):

you can activate "Catalog mode" add-on and will disable add to cart and order process

[image]